# Nodejs only sends Mongoose: details.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("5e5261c523d3fd10c0bfe4d5"), __v: 0 }, { session: null }) to database

Tags: node.js, mongoose

i have been trying to send data to my mongodb with mongoose but for some reason i only get 
`Mongoose: details.insertOne({ _id: ObjectId("5e5261c523d3fd10c0bfe4d5"), __v: 0 }, { session: null })`

on database. i am trying to send this:

```
   app.post("/cottages", (request, response) => {
  const mokki = new Mokkidb({
    name: request.body.name,
    area: request.body.area,
    size: request.body.size,
    bedrooms: request.body.bedrooms,
    beds: request.body.beds,
    address: request.body.address,
    coordinates: request.body.coordinates,
    mokin_varusteet: request.body.mokin_varusteet,
    mokin_kuvaus: request.body.mokin_kuvaus

  })
```

to my db. i have this schema made for it aswell

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.set('debug', true);
const mokkidb = new mongoose.Schema({
    mokkiId: Number,
    mokinNimi: String,
    mokinPintaAla: Number,
    henkilomaara: Number,
    makuuhuoneita: Number,
    sankyjenMaara: Number,
    osoite: String,
    koordinaatit: String,
    mokinVarusteet: String,
    mokinKuvaus: String,
    mokinKuvat: String
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("detail", mokkidb);
```

i have tried adding these too:

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

but did not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i had to have the variables named correctly (e.g mokinNimi and name had to be same)